# Clarification on the statement if request.Post: in django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have a view like this:

```
def home(request, redir_url, template = 'example/home.html')
    if request.session["profile_name"] and request.session["token"]:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redir_url)
    if request.POST:
        driver = Facebook()
        res = driver.RetLoginUrl(redir_url)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(res)

    return render(request, template)
```

In this view, first I check the session variables, if the user has already logged in, I redirect to the welcome page, and if not I have a login button with which the user can authorize my app with Facebook.

And the template has a form method=POST with the login button as input.

My question is, how does the if statement (if request.POST) get executed, when there is a statement return render(request, template) at the end of the view. After the page is rendered, i.e. return render() statement has been executed, shouldn't the view function terminate, hence without a form response being submitted to the view?

Basically, I just would like to understand the execution flow of a django view. Is the return render() statement executed first, and then waits for user input?

Comment: You should be using `request.method == 'POST'`. `request.POST` contains the post data, which may or may not be empty on a `POST` request, especially without a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
if request.method == 'POST'
```

This sentence is executed every time you access the url configured for this view. If the method of the request was POST, when the user presses the button, then the code inside `if` is executed and a HttpResponse is returned

In the example the line `render(request, template)` is only executed when the method was'nt POST (maybe GET, PUT, DELETE, etc).

Finally, you could use Django Login Decorator to avoid the session variables checking